# Unicorn+rails3.1+nginx fill the memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, ram, unicorn

I've read that Ruby doesn't return the memory to OS, it is okay. But how does it fill 512 mb of RAM? There is quite simple rails application with even one worker (i had to cut others to reduce the demand), but, anyway in few days after restart process it fills all the memory.

Thanks.